# Samesite Attribute Adjustments - AdWords & Analytics Cookies

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, samesite

[AdWords & Analytics Cookie Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCTsj.png)

Despite enabling Samesite flags per [this documentation](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug), we’re still seeing errors from sites including “adwords.google.com,” and “analytics.google.com.”

According to the documentation & warning messages we’ve received, we believe the Samesite attribute adjustment needs to be made on the Google end.

It’s specifically the Google-property sites like AdWords & Analytics that are leading us to believe that this may be the case. Can someone help us to either confirm or deny this theory?

Answer (score 0):

The console warnings do not necessarily mean that functionality is broken. The `SameSite=None; Secure` changes are only required for cross-site cookies. There are places where services may be simply leaving cookies to be restricted by default or may be explicitly *not* setting the flags for compatibility reasons.

Google properties should generally be compliant now. If you have also made any required updates, then run through your tests for your sites and services to confirm that functionality and reporting is functioning as expected.